# Is it ever necessary to use 'chomp' before using `to_i` or `to_f`?

Tags: ruby

I see people use the following code:

```
gets.chomp.to_i
```

or

```
gets.chomp.to_f
```

I don't understand why, when the result of those lines are always the same as when there is no `chomp` after `gets`.

Is `gets.chomp.to_i` really necessary, or is `gets.to_i` just enough?

Comment: I might edit this question to ask "Is it ever necessary to use the `.chomp` before a call to `.to_i`.

Comment: None of the (four) answers so far address the question.  vgoff wants to know why `chomp` is often used when it is not needed.  Also, see his comment.  I suspect it is the same reason that one often sees `self.map ...`, when `map ...` would suffice: style or ignorance.

Comment: +1 @CarySwoveland: Exactly right. I think people do it because they haven't stopped to think about what they're doing. A quick test in IRB would confirm that `chomp` was wasted CPU time.

Comment: :) Someone changed the title to do *I* need to, and I already know the answer to that.  I have not used `.chomp` in this way after I compared results in IRB in 1.8.6.  Wrote tests for it, so that I will know if that ever changes, and haven't looked back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `chomp` method because:

`String#chomp` returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of str (if present). If `$/` has not been changed from the default Ruby record separator, then `chomp` also removes carriage return characters (that is it will remove "\n", "\r", and "\r\n"). Here are some [examples](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chomp).

`String#to_f` returns the result of interpreting leading characters in `str` as a floating point number. Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at the start of `str`, 0.0 is returned. This method never raises an exception. Here are some [examples](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_f) for `to_f`.

Comment: Is this the answer? :)

Comment: i was interrupted  when creating answer.

Comment: So you are saying in this case, but in what case would you need to call chomp prior to converting it to a Numeric? Or should it be "in no case, when coercing a string to a number would you actually need to use `.chomp`.  I can not think of any case, given a string, where you use any of the `.to_i` or even `Kernel#Float` or the other methods that it would be needed, helpful or really even wanted.

Comment: Was waiting for you to edit so I could +1.  Got tired of hitting refresh. :)

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i):

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an
>   integer base base (between 2 and 36). *Extraneous characters* past the
>   end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at
>   the start of str, 0 is returned

[String#to_f](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_f) behaves the same way, excluding, of course, the base numbers.

*Extraneous characters* past the end of a valid number are ignored, this would include the newline.  So there is no need to use `chomp`.

Answer (score 2):

It is my opinion that it works the same either way, so there is no need for the `chomp` after `gets` if you are going to immediately do `to_i` or `to_f`.

In practice, I have never seen an error raised or different behavior because of leaving `chomp` out of the line.

I find it is distracting, when I see it used in answers, and there is absolutely no need for it.  It doesn't add to a "style", and it is, as @TheTinMan states, wasted CPU cycles.

Comment: `chomp` is extraneous, and adds nothing to the computation. We're supposed to be aware of our data type that's coming in. If validation is required prior to using `to_i`, then it would catch non-integer values, which `chomp` wouldn't do at all, so its place in the code has no practical value.