# Ruby random number generator

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to make a random number guessing game in Ruby. I'm rather new so perhaps the answer is obvious but why won't this work?

```
number = rand(5)
choice = 9999
while number != choice do
    puts "Guess the number #{number}"
    choice = gets.chomp
end
puts "You guessed Correctly! #{number} was the correct number."
```

As you can see I limited it to numbers between 0 and 4. Then the while loop runs while the guess made by the user is different from the random number generated. However, even when the user enters the correct number, the while loop continues looping. As you can see I've even printed the generated number so I know which to guess.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`number` is a number, `choice` is a string. You need to parse the string for this to work:

```
choice = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Comment: This answer, combined with the knowledge that [chomp does not need to precede `to_i` method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20598679/485864).

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be using something else to be comparing the *number* returned from the `rand()` function and the *string* returned from `gets`.

Perhaps the spaceship operator (`<=>`) would work, combined with turning the number into a string using `to_s`, in which case the while loop header would look like

```
while !(number.to_s <=> choice) do
```

or something like that.

You don't have to use the spaceship operator, though.

Comment: Didn't know that gets returned a string. That was my problem. Thanks!