# Whats wrong with the modulus operator in this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, modulus

```
def factors_to_three (n)
  puts n

  if n % 3 == 0
    puts "Your number is divisible by 3"
  else
    puts "Your Number is NOT divisible by 3"
  end
end

puts "Enter the number to check if its divisible by 3"
number = gets.chomp
factors_to_three(number)
```

No matter what number I input, my program always outputs `Your Number is NOT divisible by 3`, even when clearly is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result will always be `false` because `gets.chomp` returns a String:

```
number = gets.to_i
```

The above code will work but you must always type an integer. There are better ways to manage checking to see if the input is valid.

So you could check first like this:

```
number = gets
factors_to_three(number.to_i) if number.is_a?(Integer)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to `chomp` the value. `to_i` will only care about the digits in the string and will ignore the trailing new-line. See "[Is it ever necessary to use 'chomp' before using `to_i` or `to_f`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598679/is-it-ever-necessary-to-use-chomp-before-using-to-i-or-to-f)" for more information.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man, answer altered to remove the chomp.

Answer (score 3):

`n` is not an integer. `gets()` returns a string and `chomp` removes the newline, but the data is still a string.

```
"6" % 3 != 0
6 % 3 == 0
```

You need to convert your incoming data to an integer representation.

Answer (score 2):

When text is read using `gets`, it is read in as a string. So in your code, `number` is actually not a number, but a string. Because of this, the "modulus" operator is in fact *not* the modulus operator, but the format operator on `String`, [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25):

> Format—Uses str as a format specification, and returns the result of applying it to arg. If the
>   format specification contains more than one substitution, then arg
>   must be an Array or Hash containing the values to be substituted. See
>   Kernel::sprintf for details of the format string.
>
> ```
> "%05d" % 123                              #=> "00123"
> "%-5s: %08x" % [ "ID", self.object_id ]   #=> "ID   : 200e14d6"
> "foo = %{foo}" % { :foo => 'bar' }        #=> "foo = bar"
> ```

As you can see, this method returns a string, which does not equal zero. Therefore, this program will always say that the number is *not* divisible by 3, even when it is.

You can fix this by calling `to_i` on the input returned from `get`:

```
number = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `chomp`. See "[Is it ever necessary to use 'chomp' before using `to_i` or `to_f`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598679/is-it-ever-necessary-to-use-chomp-before-using-to-i-or-to-f)" for more information.