# Passing nill value to custom method

Tags: ruby

Can you please tell me why it is passing nil to check method? I am getting error `` main.rb:5:in `check': undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ``

```
my_array = Array.new
$output = String.new

def check(n)
  if n%3 == 0
    $output = $output + 'Pop '
  elsif n.even? 
    $output = $output + 'Crackle '
  elsif n.odd? 
    $output = $output + 'Snap '
  end
end

for x in 1..6
  my_array[x] = gets.chomp.to_i
end

my_array.each { |x| check(x) }

puts $output.my_array
```

Comment: `for x in 1..6..` causes `my_array[0] #=> nil`, which in turn results in `check(nil)` being executed. Indices begin at `0`, so you need `for x in 0..5`. `for loops` are *never* used. (You can google to see why.) Global variables are very rarely used. Empty arrays and strings are normally initialized `arr = []` and `str = ''`.

Comment: ...`gets.chomp.to_i` is fine but it's often shortened to `gets.to_i`.

Comment: Reference `chomp.to_i` reason to not do so at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598679/is-it-ever-necessary-to-use-chomp-before-using-to-i-or-to-f

Comment: Tip: Use `''` instead of `String.new` and `[ ]` instead of `Array.new`. The minimal form is a lot easier to understand. Also: `output << 'Snap '` is far more efficient than `output = output + 'Snap '` as it adds to the existing string, `<<` for String is the "append operator".

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting a nil in the beginning of the array is that you are manually setting the keys in the array which creates a hole since arrays are 0 indexed in Ruby:

```
ary = Array.new
ary[1] = "a"
ary[2] = "b"
ary[3] = "c"
# => [nil, "a", "b", "c"]
```

While you could salvage this code with:

```
my_array = Array.new
$output = String.new

def check(n)
  if n%3 == 0
    $output = $output + 'Pop '
  elsif n.even? 
    $output = $output + 'Crackle '
  elsif n.odd? 
    $output = $output + 'Snap '
  end
end

for x in 0..5
  my_array[x] = gets.chomp.to_i
end

my_array.each { |x| check(x) }

puts $output.my_array
```

A more idiomatically correct way to write this in Ruby is:

```
str = 5.times.map do 
  n = gets.chomp.to_i 
  if n%3 == 0
    'Pop'
  elsif n.even? 
    'Crackle'
  elsif n.odd? 
    'Snap'
  end
end.join(" ")
puts str
```

`for` `String.new` and `Array.new` are rarely used if ever used. Use blocks instead of methods unless you're planning to reuse it later. In Ruby you can use the [methods from Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html) to both iterate over and transform arrays, hashes, ranges and other types of objects so there rarely is a reason to iterate and modify an external variable like in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

With `for x in 0..5` you would then have

```
t.rb:21:in `<main>': undefined method `my_array' for "":String (NoMethodError)
```

because `my_array` is not a method that you can send to `$output`.

There are many ways to do the same thing in Ruby.

```
my_array = []

def check(n)
    case
    when n % 3 == 0
        'Pop'
    when n.even? 
        'Crackle'
    when n.odd? 
        'Snap'
    else 'boom !' # not necessary in this particular case
    end
end

(1..6).each do | i | 
    print "#{i} Enter a number > "
    my_array << gets.to_i
end

puts my_array.collect { |e| check(e) }.join(' ')
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby t.rb 
1 Enter a number > 44
2 Enter a number > 66
3 Enter a number > 30494
4 Enter a number > 383849
5 Enter a number > 2234
6 Enter a number > 4333
Crackle Pop Crackle Snap Crackle Snap
```

1. Don't use global variables, like $output. In the ancient (imperative programming style) languages, it was a common bug to inadvertently modify a variable accessible from anywhere.

   The object oriented paradigm has been invented to isolate variables (encapsulated in an
   object) to make it more difficult to modify them accidentally.

   You could have use an instance variable :

   ```
        @output = ''
        if n%3 == 0
            @output << 'Pop '
   ```

   but beeing defined in the special 'main' object, it is not protected against unwanted access.
2. chomp is not necessary before to_i, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598679/is-it-ever-necessary-to-use-chomp-before-using-to-i-or-to-f)
3. Use iterators instead of loops. `for` is imperative style (C, Java), which imposes you to manage
   the begin and end indexes. In an object oriented language, you simply send an iterate message to a
   collection object, which takes cares of the internal details.
4. `if` and `case` are expressions which return the last computed value. `check()` returns that value.
5. Your `my_array.each { |x| check(x) }` mutates the variable `$output` and returns no result. In a big program, a later maintenance could insert some processing that modifies `$output` before you use it (bug).

   The functional programming paradigm (Scala, Elixir, Kotlin) tends to use immutable variables and use functions to transform data.

   The new `my_array.collect { |e| check(e) }.join(' ')` iterates over my_array, transforms each element calling the function check(), produces a new (immutable) collection with these transformed elements, which is then transformed by the function join() to produce the final result.

Comment: Also: `6.times do |i|` where you can just offset `i`.

Comment: @tadman Then you have to manage the difference between the real world which starts at 1 and the language which starts at 0, such as `print "#{i + 1} Enter a number > "`, this is what I hate in these C derived languages ! In PL/1 the first index was 1 and life was simple :)

Comment: 0-indexed is used as a convention because it's more mathematically consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
for x in 1..6
    my_array[x] = gets.chomp.to_i
end
```

Which populates the array from indexes 1 through 6, all arrays begin at index 0 so, in your method

```
my_array.each { |x| check(x) }
```

The .each method will iterate through each element of the array, starting at 0, which in this case would be **nil** because you never assigned a value to that index, you could change your range to

```
for x in 0..6
    my_array[x] = gets.chomp.to_i
end
```

And that would work, remember to use 2 dots and not 3, as

```
0..6
0...6
```

are different, the first one is inclusive, the second one is exclusive.
You can check up more about ranges [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Range.html)

Comment: Worth noting that in Ruby you really don't use `for`.